# Firefox modal float issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, modal-dialog

I'm having this issue where firefox decides to float my modal to the left and i cant seem to figure it out. All other browsers it seems fine. the modal is positioned in the centre.

Chrome - What it should look like:
[image]

Firefox - The problem I'm having:
[image: Firefox - The problem im having]

```
.JournalReaderInner {
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.JournalReader {
    width: 640px;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should run perfect on firefox. I've tested. https://jsfiddle.net/qpzneza2/

You have mistake in the another place.

For test try:

```
position: relative !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
float: none !important;
display: block !important;
```

Comment: And it's Ok! Because, as I said, mistake in the another place :-) May be you've done mistake in the html or in the class name? it's not firefox error.

Comment: still a nope. I dont think overriding with !important helps. Seems more like a positioning problem